# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined in finding length of an array in vue.js

Tags: jquery, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this structure of data in vue.js

```
 data() {
     return {
      formData: new Form({
        files:[],
        Count:5,
        ..
  }
```

i'm trying to get the length using this code :

```
 <div class="image-input" v-if="this.formData.files.length < this.formData.Count">
```

When i run this code i'm getting this error in console :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

that error is in this line of code, v-if="this.formData.files.length < this.formData.Count"

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: you don't need to use `this` reference from template.

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo: I tried removing this but still getting same error

Comment: you mean `v-if="formData.files.length < formData.Count"` ?

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo: Yes i tried this v-if="formData.files.length < formData.Count" but getting same error at this line only

Comment: the Form class exists? because your formData is a instance of it

Comment: @ChristianCarrillo: yes it exists

Comment: I suspect that the problem is with the `Form` constructor, because I do not see anything wrong with the code that is shown.

Answer (score 0):

If you really mean to use a Form class then you need the closing right brace and right paren for the constructor and the closing right brace for the object being returned (unless you mean to imply all that with the ... :-)

But typically in Vue data we just use plain objects not classes.  So I wonder if you meant:

```
data() {
     return {
        formData:{
          files:[],
          Count:5,
          ..
         }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using 'this' operator in the template section

```
<div class="image-input" v-if="formData.files.length < formData.Count">
```